# Oracle APEX - Interactive Grid populate ID

Tags: oracle, sql-update, oracle-apex

For my Oracle APEX 5.1 application I am using an Interactive Grid which allows the users to insert multiple rows for an new issue (e.g. multiple activities). The ID is populated by an trigger.

After saving the interactive grid (separate button because I have multiple IGs on my Page), I cannot populate the ID to the new rows. But the rows need to have the same ID in order to find the correct amount of the activities.

Also I cannot update single rows. An error occurs or the whole grid updates and not a single chosen row.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "**I cannot** populate the ID to the new rows" - why not? "**But** the rows need to have the same ID" - does that trigger of yours handle that? "An **error** occurs" - which error?